# How to remove preceding zeros in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am practicing for my programming test and I came to a problem where I have to remove preceding 0's in my array.  Suppose I have an array of `[0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 3]`. My result array should be `[6, 7, 0, 3]`. My program should only remove preceding 0's only. I cannot use any inbuilt methods like array shift etc. Please suggest!

```
    boolean var=true;
    int len = a.length,counter=0; //length of main array

    int reslen = resultArr.length;  
    int [] arr = new int[len]; // new array


    for(int i =0; i<len ; i++){

        if(a[i]==0 && counter==0){
            continue;
        }else{
            arr[counter] = a[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Iterate on it and construct new array without 0's.

Comment: Show us the code you already have, with a description of how it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried starting with index `0` and iterating until you get a non-zero value in the array. then you could just left shift the elements by `k-1`. where `k` is the index of first non-zero element.

Comment: you want so people to do your homework? Do some code and show what's error is raising.

Comment: I already shared my code have a look. TheLostMind: I cannot use shift function.I have to do it mathematically.

Comment: Maroun Maroun ,The array can contains 0's if its in middle or trailing so i cant remove all 0's.

Comment: First off you need to count the leading zeros so you know how long to make the new array.  Then, since you know how many leading zeros there are, begin copying from the location where the first non-zero was found.

Comment: (And why does your question title speak of removing "trailing" zeros but the question body talks about "leading" zeros?)

Comment: Hot Licks thank you for suggestion. My code solved the preceding 0's but gave trailing 0's due to length of an array i defined. Sorry for the misleading title. I will fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not allowed to use any standard methods. In this solution there is a unnecessary loop, I would suggest you start to try and remove that as a next the challenge.

```
int[] inputArray = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 5, 0, 124, 0, 1 };

int offset = 0;

//Find out how many zeros
for (int a : inputArray) {
  if (a != 0) {
    break;
  }
  offset++;
}

//Create an array of the correct size:
int[] outputArray = new int[inputArray.length - offset];

//Copy the array
for (int i = 0; i < outputArray.length; i++) {
  outputArray[i] = inputArray[i + offset];
}

//Only used to confirm solution.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 5, 0, 124, 0, 1]
[5, 2, 1, 5, 0, 124, 0, 1]
```

Comment: thanks, have a nice day and remember; You can't be a good programmer without knowing the basics. Keep going! :)

Comment: Instead of looping second time for copy you could use `System.arraycopy`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is broken. Debug your code to understand your problem.

I suggest that you use [`Arrays#copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) method:

```
int index = findFirstNonZero(a);
//some checks?
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, index, a.length);
```

Where `findFirstNonZero` is a method *you'll* implement.

After you mentioned that you cannot use built in methods I'll tell you what's your problem.

Your condition `if(a[i]==0 && counter==0)` won't be met for coming zeros, so it'll insert them although they are not at the beginning. You should:

1. Mark first non-zero element, `i`
2. Iterate from `i` until the end of the array and construct new array

Comment: Using any built-in copy function is presumably not allowed.

Comment: @HotLicks Just noticed that, added details.

Answer (score -1):

```
    boolean flag=false;
    List<Integer> a2=new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        if(a1[i]==0 &&flag==false){
            continue;
        }else{
            flag=true;
           a2.add(a1[i]);  
        }

    }

    System.out.println(a2);
```